# Trying to open a new window and create elements inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So what I've been trying to do is open a new small window that its size is 500x500 and create new divs with JS/ Jquery inside it.

html:

```
<body>
      <div class="contain ">  </div>
</body>
```

```
newWindow = window.open("replaceWindow.html", "newWindow", "width=500,height=500");

newWindow.onload = () =>{
  let newDiv =  newWindow.document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.className = "card-body"
  newWindow.document.getElementByClassName('contain').appendChild(newDiv);
}
```

Still `contain` doesn't append `newDiv`.

Comment: `.contain` doesn't exist in `newWindow`. It only exists in `window`.

Comment: Then how do I create divs and design it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when your *first* initial window is loaded, it is **cached**. Therefore, when creating a *new* window from the *first* window, the contents of the new window are not loaded from the server, but are loaded from the cache. Consequently, no `onload` event occurs when you create the *new* window.

However, in this case, an `onpageshow` event occurs. It always occurs after the `onload` event and even when the page is *loaded* from cache.

This is explained on the [w3school website](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onpageshow.asp):

> The onpageshow event is similar to the `onload` event, except that it occurs after the onload event when the page first loads. Also, the `onpageshow` event occurs every time the page is loaded, whereas the onload event does not occur when the page is loaded from the cache.

So, this is a working solution to your problem using `onpageshow` event listener on `newWindow` instead of `onload`:

```
var newWindow = window.open("replaceWindow.html", "newWindow", "width=500,height=500");

newWindow.onpageshow = () => {
    let newDiv =  newWindow.document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.className = "card-body";
    newWindow.document.getElementsByClassName('contain').item(0).appendChild(newDiv);
}
```